# Different results in SQL vs. VBA using POWER function and VBA equivalent

Tags: sql, vba, function, ms-access

I'm hoping someone who is actually good at math can help me out with this.  I get a different result in SQL than I do in VBA.  In SQL, I have this function that calculates a payment.  Variables for both VBA and SQL are:

- Principal = 239762.05
- Rate = 0.03 (aka 3%) ETA: in both cases, 0.03 is divided by 12, so really this is .0025
- Period = 268

  @principal / (power(1+@rate,@period)-1) * (@rate*power(1+@rate,@period))

In SQL this gives a value of **1228.76** (rounded)

In VBA, I do not have the POWER function.  So I copied this public function from the internet:

```
Public Function Power(ByVal number As Double, ByVal exponent As Double) As Double
Power = number ^ exponent
End Function
```

And I am calling it in a sub here like so:

```
NewPI = PrinBal / (Power(1 + IntCalc, Term) - 1) * (IntCalc * Power(1 + IntCalc, Term))
```

but here, the answer I get is **1228.63** (rounded).  Only 13 cents off!

I have tried lots of adjustments and either ended up with this same figure, or a much worse result.  I am thinking it's some sort of Order of Operations mistake, but I'm not sure.

**EDIT**

I am adding this to possibly get to the bottom of the problem, which might be the data types in the SQL version.  This is the full function

```
create function [dbo].[PMT] (@rate numeric(15,9), @periods smallint, @principal numeric(20,2) )  
returns numeric(16,2)  
as   

begin  
declare @pmt numeric (38,9)  
select @pmt = @principal / (power(1+@rate,@periods)-1) * (@rate*power(1+@rate,@periods))  
return @pmt  
end
```

Comment: I run your code as TSQL and the resultant value is ~7195.47.  You sure that code is correct?

Comment: oops sorry, it's supposed to be variable IntCalc, which is defined as Double and is InterestRate/12 (0.03 / 12) aka 0.0025

Comment: 1228.63 is the right answer.

Comment: @LDMJoe here's the statement with values instead of variables     select 239762.05 / (power(1+0.0025,268)-1) * (0.0025*power(1+0.0025,268))   as 'Value!'

Comment: @Barranka if this is so, why is SQL giving that wrong answer?

Comment: In the literal, you are using a value of 0.0025 - the variable is set to 0.03 in your pseudocode.

Comment: @LDMJoe sorry check edit of my post

Comment: @msim are you using MS Access or SQL server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Data types in SQL matter.

Worse, you can experience some implicit data conversion.  Check this out...

```
DECLARE @RealPrincipal real

SET @RealPrincipal = 239762.05

DECLARE @RealRate real
SET @RealRate = 0.0025 --0.03 --(aka 3%) ETA: in both cases, 0.03 is divided by 12, so really this is .0025

DECLARE @Period int
SET @Period = 268

SELECT @RealPrincipal / (power(1.0+@RealRate,@Period)-1.0) * (@RealRate*power(1.0+@RealRate,@Period))
```

Result = 1228.61333410069

Compare that to your formula from your OP comment with all literals and no variables...

```
SELECT  239762.05 / (power(1+0.0025,268)-1) * (0.0025*power(1+0.0025,268)) as 'Value!'
```

Result = 1228.761629

Now, use the same exact structure as the first code block, but replace the `real` type variables with `money` type...

```
DECLARE @moneyPrincipal money

SET @moneyPrincipal = 239762.05
DECLARE @moneyRate money
SET @moneyRate = 0.0025 --(aka 3%) ETA: in both cases, 0.03 is divided by 12, so moneyly this is .0025

DECLARE @Period int
SET @Period = 268

SELECT @moneyPrincipal / (power(1+@moneyRate,@Period)-1) * (@moneyRate*power(1+@moneyRate,@Period))
```

Result = 1233.2921

Now, using the money data types, watch what happens when you replace the literal `1` values in the formula with `1.0` ...

```
SELECT @moneyPrincipal / (power(1.0+@moneyRate,@Period)-1.0) * (@moneyRate*power(1.0+@moneyRate,@Period))
```

Result = 1228.761629

Comment: Ack!  I totally missed the MS-Access tag when answering.  First, my sincerest condolences.  Also, I have no idea if my answer still applies or not now.  If not, leave a comment and I'll remove it.  Access's bastardized TSQL may(?) be close enough that this still has value, so until I hear otherwise, I'll leave it for now.

Comment: this is excellent knowledge to have as I learn more about both SQL and VBA.  I will edit my question to give you the data types the SQL version is using, and perhaps this is the root of the problem

Comment: Okay, please see edit below in my original question.  To be clear, when I'm doing this calc in SQL I'm in MS SSMS

Comment: Then yes, the root of your problem is absolutely data types and the sig figs supported by them.  Data types like [numeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) can be particularly hairy when you start mixing values for precision and scale.

Comment: fascinating!  So what i'm getting here is that VBA double data type is more precise than SQL numeric data type, so my VBA is actually correct, or at least moreso.  Is there a more precise data type in VBA than double that I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simplify your calculation:

In VBA:

```vb
function payment(principal as double, rate as double, term as integer) as double
' Inputs:
'    principal: Ammount of the loan
'    rate: Effective interest rate per period
'    term: Number of periods / payments
    dim v as double, a as double
    v = 1 / (1 + rate)
    a = (1 - (v ^ term) / rate)
    payment = principal / a
end function
```

or, if you want it squeezed into a single line:

```vb
function payment(principal as double, rate as double, term as integer) as double
' Inputs:
'    principal: Ammount of the loan
'    rate: Effective interest rate per period
'    term: Number of periods / payments
    payment = principal * rate / (1 - ((1 + rate) ^ (-term)))
end function
```

and, in SQL:

```sql
@principal * @rate / (1 - power(1 + @rate, -@term))
-- @rate is the effective rate per period (in your example: 0.0025)
```

Minimize the number of arithmetic operations.

---

If you're having problems with data type (as LDMJoe mentions in his answer), you should try casting each variable to an appropriate data type. In Access you can do something like this (assuming you're writing the expression in a query):

```
CDbl(principal) * CDbl(rate) / (1 - power(1 + CDbl(rate), -CInt(term))
```

I'm also assuming that `principal`, `rate` and `term` are columns in a table.

Comment: I will try this in VBA but in SQL with the above variable values, this results in 1228.54

Comment: @msim Why are you trying to do this directly as an SQL expression when you have it done with VBA? (just curious)

Comment: @msim And... I didn't know MS-Access supported user variables in queries... are you *really* using MS-Access? Or are you using SQL-Server or other RDBMS?

Comment: Thanks Barranka, this was originally done in MS SSMS and I am converting the project to MS Access VBA.  The different values was a concern that I wanted to look into to make sure I'm getting it right.

Comment: @msim Check my update on how to deal with type conversions in Access.

Comment: Thanks, principal, rate, and term are not columns, they are variables in VBA defined as Double, Double, and Integer, respectively.  So luckily I think I've chosen the right data types in VBA.  There's a possibility the wrong data types are chosen in SQL, and therefore my VBA result is correct but my SQL result is the one that is slightly off

Comment: @msim Then I suggest you use the VBA function instead of building it directly into the query (since Access does not support variables in the queries AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simply explanation. VBA is simply using a higher precision then SQL. Not saying this is best practice and i am sure someone else it going to SLAP / downvote me but if you change it too something like the below you will see it forces SQL to use more decimal places and you get the same answer.

> select
>   @principal/(POWER((@rate+1)*1.000000000,@period*1.00000000000000000)-1)*(@rate*POWER((@rate+1)*1.0000000000000000000,@period*1.00000000000000000))

Again there are better ways to do this, this is just the quick and dirty.